# Why isn't HCl called hydrogen monochloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

Since HCl is a covalent compound, then it would be expected to be called hydrogen ***mono***chloride following the rules for naming. Instead it is named as if it were an ionic compound, without any prefixes. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Why not call it monohydrogen monochloride? If it's unambiguous you leave away anything that could describe "mono-".